# Updating a Paradox Table at RunTime

Tags: sql, delphi, runtime

I'm currently using the following method to add a field to a paradox table at run time.

```
procedure TfrmMain.AddField(UpdTable, FieldName, FieldType: string);
begin
 with qryUpdate do
 begin
  Close;
  ParamByName('UPDTABLE').AsString := UpdTable;
  ParamByName('FLDNAME').AsString  := FieldName;
  ParamByName('FLDTYPE').AsString  := FieldType;
  ExecSQL;
  Open;
 end;
end;

procedure TfrmMain.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  AddField('Test','newfield', 'VARCHAR(30)');
end;
```

In the component called 'qryUpdate' I have the following query:

```
ALTER TABLE :UPDTABLE
ADD :FLDNAME :FLDTYPE
```

However when the query is executed the following message is displayed:

> Invalid use of keyword.
>
> Token: ?
>
> Line Number: 1.

What am I doing wrong?

Another (related) question:
Will adding fields like this to an existing database harm the existing fields/data at all?

Comment: Have you tried running the SQL outside of you application. or monitoring it?

Comment: I have just ran the query (I replaced all of the parameters with the ones I am passing into it with the program) and it worked fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only add the field once to the table! Your code, as written, will try to add the field every time you run the program. You should first check to see how many fields your table contains prior to adding the new field.

I used to use the following code to add fields at runtime (this is for BDE/Paradox tables)

```
with ttable.create (nil) do
 try
  databasename:= 'whatever';
  tablename:= 'test.db';
  open;
  fc:= fieldcount;
  close;
 finally
  free
 end;

if fc = 7 then
 with tquery.create (nil) do
  try
   databasename:= 'whatever';
   close;
   sql.add ('alter table "test.db" add newfield varchar (30)');
   execsql
  end;
   finally
  free
 end;
```

Note that my syntax of the 'alter table' statement is different from yours - the tablename is enclosed in quotation marks and includes the file's extension.

Comment: This application is for updating another piece of software I have written hence why it's adding them on startup. When I get back tonight I'll give your code a shot, probably put it into a procedure so I can call it multiple times for various fields.  Also Can I ask, why are you fetching the number of fields and using it to determine whether the field should eb added or not?

Comment: @MoonPunch: Checking the number of fields lets me know whether the field has already been added.

Comment: Could you not perform an if statement on the field name to determine whether or not the specified field exists instead of a integer?